# A necessary and sufficient condition for $\langle (g,h) \rangle = \langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ abd $H$ be finite groups and let $(g,h) \in G \oplus H.$ Then what is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\langle (g,h) \rangle = \langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle$

**Attempt of a solution :**

If $|g|=m,|h|=n$, then, $|\langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle|=mn=|\langle (g,h )\rangle|$ only when $\gcd (m,n)=1$.

$\langle (g,h) \rangle = \{(g,h), (g^2,h^2),\cdots,(e,e)\}$

I am not very sure how to go about this problem after this.

Could anyone please tell me how to proceed ahead?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By «$(g,h)\in G\oplus H$» do you mean that $g\in G$ and $h\in H$?

Comment: yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Then what does $\langle g,h\rangle$ mean? As $g$ and $h$ are not in the same group, the notation does not mean anything!

Comment: $\langle g,h \rangle$ mean the cyclic group generated by $(g,h)?$ My best guess is that's what my textbook is saying?

Comment: Well, then what you meant to write is $\langle(g,h)\rangle$, **not** $\langle g, h\rangle$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ohh thanks for pointing out. I will edit my question.

Comment: Do make the change in all appearences of $\langle g,h\rangle$.

Comment: Done. I have edited them

Comment: Any hints regard to this problem? :)

Comment: I think you are well on track, and you should think more about it :-)

Comment: Haven't you solved it already?

Comment: @Qidi I think I have only proved that for the cardinality for the two sets to be equal, the desired result should be valid. But two sets can be non equivalent even after having the same cardinality

Comment: @ShreyaTaneja I don't understand your comment? If $gcd(m,n)=1$ $(g,h)$ has order $mn$ and generates a subgroup of $\langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle$ of full cardinality, hence the entire group. Conversely $\langle (g,h) \rangle = \langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle$ implies it is cyclic, and the generator $(g,h)$ has order the cardinality $mn$, then $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting point: argue it is necessary+sufficient for $(g,0)$ and $(0,h)$ to be powers of $(g,h)$.